# 'EntityState' is not a valid property on type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf-data-services, odata

I've enabled OData as described here:
http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/odata-enable
I've ended up with the cursed "An error occurred while processing this request." error. I then Googled around until I found out how to turn on debugging, as per the instructions here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phaniraj/archive/2008/06/18/debugging-ado-net-data-services.aspx
Now I'm seeing that the cause of the problem is an 'EntityState' property:

The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The property 'EntityState' on type 'Game' is not a valid property. Make sure that the type of the property is a public type and a supported primitive type or a entity type with a valid key or a complex type.'.

Doing a search over my code, I can't even find an 'EntityState' property, leading me to think this is an internal .net property.
So ... what causes this, and how do I either fix it, or work around it?

Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace, the exception and its inner exception, please?

Comment: Without the stack trace I am guessing the type you are using isn't a ObjectContext type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the stack trace I am guessing the type you are using isn't a ObjectContext type